# Need help with Python code

Tags: gpio, python, led

I hadn't programmed on my RPi for a couple of months due to me focusing mainly on my education. Yesterday, finally the school year ended, and so I decided to start programming on my Pi again from the beginning.
I wired everything up correctly using my breadboard and started creating some simple programs that altered my LED's state from on to off, dimming, etc...
BTW it's an RGB led.
I decided to write a code that would let you choose what colour you wanted the LED to light up in, however, it doesn't seem to work.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(11,0)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(13,0)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(15,0)

try:
    while(True):
        request = raw_input("RGB -->")
        if (request == 1):
            GPIO.output(11,1)
        elif (request == 2):
            GPIO.output(13,1)
        elif (request == 3):
            GPIO.output(15,1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I choose a colour nothing happens, can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function returns a **string** not an **int**. So when your code reaches the if statement you are comparing an int and a string. Since 1 (an int) does not match "1" (a string) the program reaches the end without matching any of the if or elif statements.

To fix the problem change your code to this:

```
if (int(request) == 1):
    GPIO.output(11,1)
elif (int(request) == 2):
    GPIO.output(13,1)
elif (int(request) == 3):
    GPIO.output(15,1)
```

or alternatively:

```
request = raw_input("RGB -->")
request = int(request)
if (request == 1):
    GPIO.output(11,1)
elif (request == 2):
    GPIO.output(13,1)
elif (request == 3):
    GPIO.output(15,1)
```

A good defensive programming strategy is to always include an else clause in your if statemnent. Something like this:

```
else:
    print("no match found")
```

This way your program will print an informative message rather than silently failing.

Comment: I much prefer doing the conversion once, that's far more efficient. Though your use of `()` in `if` statements is rather unpythonic. I'd suggest removing those.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I agree it is unpythonic but is based on the OP's code. The efficiency is why I included the second alternative.